# Using MS Build to deploy after tests

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I have a web project structured the following way:

WebSite
WebSite.test

In the test project, I have all the unit tests (using Microsoft test framework). In the WebSite project I have a target to deploy the site using MSDeploy, the MSDeployPublish target, and DeployOnBuild=true. I then run this build using Jenkins. The problem is that using this setup, the site will get deployed before it's tested.

I could add another build step in Jenkins, so that the entire solution is built first, then the deploy projects are run. However, I would like for it all to be in one step. Is this at all possible?

Comment: I've having the same issue but with vanilla TFS builds; I'd love to see a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in Jenkins. See [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-263) ([or this one](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2002)). See comments for possible workarounds.